# PopupWindow set animation style programmatically

Tags: android, animation, webview, popupwindow

I want to create `PopupWindow` with `WebView` inside usung slide up and slide down animation on it. The problem is, I want to put it in jar file so I cannot use xml.

Is it possible to set animation style programmatically for popup windows in Android?

If not, is there any way to achieve `PopupWindow` with animation effect?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have to create a `style` like

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@drawable/slide_in_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@drawable/slide_out_down</item>
</style>
```

where `slide_in_up` and `slide_out_down` are your animation files. After this create a `Dialog` object in your activity like

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(tabGroupActivity, R.style.Dialog);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I said that I cannot use xml files. That's the whole problem.

Comment: How to use TranslateAnimation on PopupWindow ? PopupWindow doesn't have startAnimation method.